# Are "pots of memory" an historical custom?

Tags: cultural-history, family

I found a term **"pots of memory"** in a novel.  I searched on the web but I could not find any clues.

The novel, "Kokushikan Satsujinjiken" by Mushitaro Oguri was published 1934 in Japan and people might have inaccurate knowledge about English culture at that time.  The author might have misunderstood it or made up that story.  I'd like to know whether the custom is real or not.

About the novel and its settings:

- The setting of the novel is in the 1930's Japan.  And it picks a muder case in a family.
- The author sets that the family was established by a child between a Japanese man and [Bianca Cappello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bianca_Cappello) (1548 - 1587), an Italian noble.
- Because of its origin, the family is familiar with western calture.
- In the novel, the term is written in English (transcription in Katakana) not only in Japanese.  So it is originally English term and translation should be correct.

About the pots:

- Pots stand on a mantelpiece in a salon of a mansion.
- Member of a family create a pot out of clay by their hand.
- The pots serve something to remember their creator even after his death.
- The pots are glazed in Spanish style.  It is unclear whether such decoration is common on the custom.  It might be a special option in the family.  And this is a point of difference from [memory jugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_jug).
- Sometimes people who have an important relationship with the family (a designer of the mansion, in the novel) also create it.

Comment: Welcome to the site - and congratulations on the quality of your first question. I have suggested to the community that the question be migrated, so please wait on a decision in case I may be incorrect in my judgement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I believe that https://japanese.stackexchange.com/ is likely a better location for this question.

Comment: This is an historical question, not a Japanese language question. Therefore it's on scope here, not in japanese.se.

Comment: Since there doesn't appear to be an English translation available, in what part of the English-speaking world, and in what era, is this novel set? An English translation of the passage where this thing is described would be a big plus.

Comment: Is the description in the novel similar to these [memory jugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_jug)?

Comment: I gather that this was published in [1956](https://www.worldcat.org/title/kokushikan-satsujin-jiken/oclc/674239801), which is around the time when the flow of English derived [Gairaigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gairaigo) really took off.  It is not unknown for these to include [things that weren't imported from overseas](https://translate.google.com/?um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&client=tw-ob#ja/en/%E3%82%BB%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9)

Comment: @StevenBurnap Where did you get that date? I'm seeing 1935. (For example, [here](http://martinhillortiz.blogspot.com/2015/07/around-world-in-mystery-part-two-and.html?m=1)).

Comment: https://www.worldcat.org/title/kokushikan-satsujin-jiken/oclc/674239801/editions?sd=desc&referer=di&se=yr&qt=facet_yr%3A&editionsView=true&fq=yr%3A1935 shows 1935.

Comment: I was looking at [this](https://www.worldcat.org/title/kokushikan-satsujin-jiken/oclc/674239801).  I guess it was a reprint.

Comment: Thank you for comments!  I added some information about the novel.  About the publish year; the novel appeared on a magazine in 1934 and published as a book in 1935.

Comment: @rad164. Please edit all information into the question.  The question should contain all the information you know.  People are reluctant to read long comment strings.

Comment: There are a number of relevant-looking web results for "memory pots".

Comment: An English translation of the passage where this term appears might give people enough context to answer the question.